# Understanding random number generation

Tags: random, game-maker

I'm creating a game where I want to create random worlds and give the player the option of having the same world made again by entering the same seed...
So... How can I do this? It will generate the same set of numbers, but not the same every time you call for the random function...

Do I have to make function of sorts based on the seed manually?

Comment: A good example of what I want is the way Minecraft worlds does it...

Comment: Understanding how random numbers are generated in language/framework of your choice would be good start and let you improve your question.

Comment: thx for the tip. kinda tired as i've been doing an all nighter.

Answer (score 1):

In GameMaker Studio and GameMaker 8.1 there is a function:
`random_set_seed(seed)`

Here you can enter your seed. 
Then `random(x)` gives the same n-th result per game run.

```
random(100)
randomize() // This doesn't change rand[0] or rand[1]

random_set_seed(20) // because of this
rand[0]=random(100)
rand[1]=random(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Randomizer functions either use mathematical formulas which seem to give out random numbers or just look at an already calculated array of seemingly random numbers and return them in order. In most languages, there is a function which will look at the computer's clock and will use this value as a first value for the mathematical formula or as a starting index in the pseudorandom array. In GameMaker, you can use `randomize()` to do that. Only call that once when the game launches and you'll get different results on every execution.

If you want the opposite, that is you want to be able to regenerate the same seemingly random sequence, you can instead set the seed manually with `random_set_seed(value)`. The value passed needs to be a number. Then you can give that seed to the player.

So if you want to generate a random level on the first time and later be able to replay the same level, you need to do in order:

- Call `randomize` to set a random seed.
- Call `random_get_seed` which will return the current seed.
- Call `random` and the likes to generate a level.
- When the player wants to use the same seed as before, call `random_set_seed` and pass it the seed.

> Warning: By using those functions, you are putting your trust in GM's randomizing functions. These are platform dependent, and the functions might change in a later version of GM. If you want your seeds to work across all platforms and versions of your game, you might want to work on your own randomizing functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. Not hitting the answer I'm looking for here though!

Say you have a button "Create world" and a input for the seed.
Every time you click "Create world" (reguardless of how many random() calls before it) needs to create the same world every time. This doesn't when I try it...